# .htaccess RewriteRule not working the way I need it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having some issues with the .htaccess and RewriteRule. I've searched for similar topics for hours, but nothing seems to work. Do you have any idea what is wrong with my code?

So I am trying to make http://localhost/myproject/post.php?p_id=92 look like this http://localhost/myproject/post/92. If I use the below code, the page http://localhost/myproject/post/92 loads,but there is no post content (only sidebar,nav etc)

In .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(index|contact|registration)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)$ post.php?p_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

In HTML I have:

```
<a href="post/<?php echo $post_id; ?>"><?php echo $post_title ?></a>
```

I have tested many other ways and it seems that if I remove the post/ or replace the / with -, the page loads as expected.

For example, I can make the URL http://localhost/myproject/post-92 with the below code and it works properly:

```
RewriteRule ^post-(\d+)$ post.php?p_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Or I can make the URL http://localhost/myproject/92 with the below change:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ post.php?p_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

How can I make the URL look like http://localhost/myproject/post/92 ? I don't understand why the above 2 options work, but the one I need does not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)/?$ post.php?p_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(index|contact|registration)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Two changes are:

1. Turning off `MultiViews` so that content negotiation services are turned off
2. Keep `post` rule on top so that other may not affect it when you add `post` in that rule's alternations.